# mod_rewrite but skip a directory

Tags: mod-rewrite, directory

I'm attempting to avoid urls like this one:

images/

or

images/valid-filename.png

or

images/invalid-filename.png

from being rewritten

and I've checked other example questions like [.htaccess mod_rewrite on root directory but need it to skip all other directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328118/htaccess-mod-rewrite-on-root-directory-but-need-it-to-skip-all-other-directorie) and [.htaccess mod_rewrite exemptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717637/htaccess-mod-rewrite-exemptions) and this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209746/can-mod-rewrite-skip-a-folder but I've not managed to get the rules to achieve what I'm after.

Here is what I have right now:

```
# Enable URL Rewriting
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^(scripts|styles|images)(/.*|$) - [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/robots.txt
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  # ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  # This solved the problem
  # ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !images/.* [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

If I navigate to **www.site.com/images/**, I get redirected to www.site.com

If I navigate to **www.site.com/images/invalid-filename.png**, I get redirected to www.site.com

but **www.site.com/images/valid-filename.png** loads correctly.

Could someone help to explain how to achieve the rewrite behaviour described above?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this RewriteCond: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !images/.* [NC]`
It will check whether the URI begins with `images/` and if it does, the rule will not be met.

Comment: Hi Christopher Brix. That was perfect.  This condition belongs after the other RewriteCond rules.  I've updated my question to reflect your answer.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually - spoke to soon - a php script returned 'exit' on the url so this didn't actually work in the end - but just appeared to. Any possible modifications to try?

Comment: @MyStream That's strange. It's working for me. AND: Your first RewriteRule `RewriteRule ^(scripts|styles|images)(/.*|$) - [L]` avoids every url starting with `images` from being rewritten, too.
You could add `R=302` to your second RewriteRule. This would force a redirect so you could see whether the rule is met or not. Maybe there is a totally different error?